# Android Studio: BottomNavigationView and transaction between fragments

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to implement **BottomNavigationView** from Jetpack

```
def nav_version = "2.0.0"
// Java language implementation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

**First test** was done excluding the commented lines presented below and the transactions were done automatically by the library.

This way, the problem I faced was: if I press 100 times the bottom menu, I need to press 100 times the back button to do all the way back to MainFragment.

**Second test** was done uncommenting the commented lines and the transactions were hardcoded.

This way, the problem I faced was: The Fragment content overlapped one another and I could not figure out what I was doing wrong.

Because of an unsuccessful **second test**, I run the app without the commented lines (**I deleted it**) presented below once again, but the automatic transaction by the library (experienced in the **first test**) is not working anymore. I mean only the MainFragment is been launched, the others are not.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "debinf MainActivity";

    //public static final String FRAGMENT_KEY = "fragment";

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavController navController;

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_bottomnav);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_sidebar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);

        setupNavigation();

        // Fragment been created for the first time
        /*if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_KEY) == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: First fragment been created: MainFragment()");
            fragmentTransaction(new MainFragment());
        }*/

    }

    private void setupNavigation() {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupNavigation: ");
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment);

        appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
        // Listener for bottomNavigation must be called after been setupWithNavController
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    /*private void fragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fragmentTransaction: Hardcoded Transaction");
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out)
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment, null)
                .commit();
    }*/



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed: ");
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSupportNavigateUp: ");
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: ");

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.mainFragment) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: mainFrag");
            //fragmentTransaction(new MainFragment()); // Hardcoded transaction
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.shopFragment) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: shopFrag");
            //fragmentTransaction(new ShopFragment()); // Hardcoded transaction
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.searchFragment) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: searchFragment");
            //fragmentTransaction(new SearchFragment()); // Hardcoded transaction
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

What do I have to do to have the automatic transaction by the Jetpack library back?

P.S.: I have not changed a bit of code anywhere else besides what is shown in the code above.

**EDIT**

Below is **nav_graph.xml** I would like to press back button one time to go back to MainFragment and press back button again to leave the app (**first test problem**).

I appreciate any help!

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainnav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.aelecomerce.goodstag.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/shopFragment"
        android:name="com.aelecomerce.goodstag.ShopFragment"
        android:label="fragment_shop"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_shop" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/openAddstoreFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addstoreFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"/>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/openBarcodeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/barcodeFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.aelecomerce.goodstag.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addstoreFragment"
        android:name="com.aelecomerce.goodstag.AddstoreFragment"
        android:label="fragment_addstore"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_addstore" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/barcodeFragment"
        android:name="com.aelecomerce.goodstag.BarcodeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_barcode"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_barcode" />
</navigation>
```

Below is the menu for the BottomNavigationView

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@id/mainFragment"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call_on_hold"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"/>

    <item
        android:id="@id/shopFragment"
        android:title="Shop"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call_on_hold"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"/>

    <item
        android:id="@id/searchFragment"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call_on_hold"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"/>

</menu>
```

And below is the **main_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/main_bottomnav"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mainnav_graph"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/main_bottomnav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/main_navmenu"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/botton_item_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/botton_item_color">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_sidebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/main_sidebarmenu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

As that is overriding the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` set by `setupWithNavController()`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It worked! But how to get rid of the stacking of fragments? I would like to press back button one time and go to MainFragment and press the second time to leave the app.

Comment: That's what you get by default, so it sounds like you changed your navigation graph in a way that broke the default behavior, most likely in popping the startDestination off the back stack. You'd need to include your navigation graph file in a question to give anyone a chance to debug what that totally separate problem is.

Comment: I added the main xml files at the bottom of the question scope.

Comment: You'll want to remove all of the `android:menuCategory="secondary"` in your options menu - as per the [`onNavDestinationSelected` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI?hl=en#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)), `secondary` specifically means "don't pop the back stack", which is why you get multiple copies.

Comment: You are absolutely right once again. All problems solved! Thank you!